# Custom net.Resolver bypassed when localhost queried

Tags: http, go

I have a `http.Transport` that uses a custom `Resolver`. Given that this code is for a proxy server, I want to deny requests towards localhost and hosts that resolve to private addresses.

```
func Resolver() *net.Resolver {
    return &net.Resolver{
        PreferGo: true,
        Dial: func(ctx context.Context, network, address string) (conn net.Conn, err error) {
            host, port, err := net.SplitHostPort(address)
            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }

            if host == "localhost" {
                return nil, fmt.Errorf("localhost is forbidden")
            }

            ... resolve the address
        },
    }
}
```

The problem is that golang's `net` package seems to have a [hardcoded way](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17.5:src/net/conf.go;drc=52f68efa45a34e60e8fc5a2ad5fc124a865ac2a4;l=124) of resolving addresses in which it first checks for entries in `/etc/hosts` and replies immediately if a value is found inside there - bypassing my resolver. I tried with `PreferGo` `false` or `true` without a difference.

How can I make this transport to forcefully go through my resolver?

Comment: the address you are testing against is the address of the reference remote dns server, it is *not* the address to resolve for an hypothetical dial operation from an hypothetical (http) client. https://pkg.go.dev/net#Resolver `Dial optionally specifies an alternate dialer for use by Go's built-in DNS resolver to make TCP and UDP connections to DNS services.`

Comment: Got it. I understand it now. I'm working on the wrong part to enforce this limitation. Thanks.